# Apex: action status not working on Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I am having the below piece of code...My expectation is when command button is clicked, action status will work and change the button value to processing... however this is not working. Kindly suggest.

```
   <apex:actionStatus id="mySaveStatus1">
     <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="{!$Label.Submit_Request}"  status="mySaveStatus1"/>
         </apex:facet>
     <apex:facet name="start">
         <apex:outputPanel >
               <apex:image value="/img/loading32.gif" style="height: 15px;"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Processing..." status="mySaveStatus1" disabled="true"/>
           </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
```

Comment: No..there is no change in button name with this code.

Comment: add rerender="mySaveStatus1" to first command button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed `rerender` in `apex:commandButton`:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pgblck">
    <apex:actionStatus id="mySaveStatus">
        <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" 
                status="mySaveStatus" rerender="pgblck"/>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:image value="/img/loading32.gif" style="height: 15px;"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Processing..." 
                    status="mySaveStatus" disabled="true"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
</apex:pageBlock>
```